# Laravel Livewire with Google Analytics 4

Tags: laravel-livewire, google-analytics-4

I have a Laravel Livewire project and I need to track visitors. I have configured Google Analytics 4 and I need to insert it into the Livewire code.

resources/views/analytics.blade.php

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'xxxxxx');
</script>
```

Then in view/layouts/app.blade.php I have inserted it as follows:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

<!-- Scripts -->
@include('google_analytics')
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

When looking at the page source, I cannot see any reference to Google Analytics and consequently I don't see anything in Google Analytics.

Anyone knows how to do this with Laravel Livewire?